# How do I use the "If" function with hh:mm?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use the `IF` function with the `hh:mm` format. The objective is to reduce a calculated time  by 30 mins IF the total time is equal to or over 9 hours.

Here is the formula I was trying to use, but it doesn't work:

`IF(time(hour(T3),minute(t3)<=9, -0,TIME(HOUR(T3), MINUTE(T3) - 30, SECOND(T3))).`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: I will need to convert the answer back to decimal format so that I can re-insert the result into a spreadsheet. Would it be useful to convert to decimal prior to trying to action the "IF" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date values in Excel are in fact numeric - to put it short it's *number of days since January 1, 1900.* I.e. `41948.5` means `05 November, 2014 12:00`. So one hour equals to `1/24=0.041666...`. In your case:

```
=IF(MOD(T3,1)>=9/24,T3-0.5/24,T3)
```

Comment: Taosique..works perfectly thank you, I will try and understand the logic ..appreciate your help